# Load two sites on startup in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, batch-file, load, internet-explorer-9, startup

I am using IE9 and I'm trying to load two web pages on startup.

Originally it was loading one but now I need to see 2 different pages, preferably tabs but not necessary, whatever is easier.

Here is the original code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content="10;URL=http://www.gmail.com">

<title>Loading application...</title>

</head>

<body>
<h1>
PLEASE WAIT...!!!
</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

and I tried creating a batch file to open 2 different iexplore.exe with 2 different websites but it didn't work. It would only open the 2nd iexplore after the first one was closed.

```
@echo off

SET BROWSER=iexplore.exe
START %BROWSER% "http://www.cnn.com"
SLEEP 10
START %BROWSER% "http://www.gmail.com"
```

**NOTE:** I **need** a 10 second delay to open gmail.com (or one of the sites). That's where I'm getting stuck, otherwise I would just set the home pages to these two and add a shortcut to iexplore.exe to the startup folder.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This works fine for me on Windows 7 32 bit. Change iexplorer to iexplore in your script above. You typed it wrong. Better to copy and paste your script.

Comment: @MattWilliamson I have it on another computer, that's why hehe. I modified it and yes it work but the second page does not take 10 seconds to load. It does it at the same time

Answer (score 0):

```
SET BROWSER=iexplore.exe
START /w %BROWSER% "http://www.cnn.com"
SLEEP 10
START %BROWSER% "http://www.gmail.com"
```

`START /W` to wait for finishing the execution.And internet explorer exe is named iexplore.exe.

Comment: yeah I just changed it to iexplore.exe, it was a typo

Comment: for some reason is not waiting those 10 seconds

Comment: try this instead of sleep `w32tm /stripchart /computer:localhost /period:1 /dataonly /samples:10  >nul 2>&1`

Comment: or `ping -n 10 localhost>nul 2>&1`

Comment: `PING -n 10 127.0.0.1 >NUL 2>&1 || PING -n 10 ::1 >NUL 2>&1`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open the second page in a new tab, IE has to be your default browser. The following works for me. I don't have sleep, so I substituted the ping for it.

```
@echo off
setlocal
SET BROWSER=iexplore.exe
START %BROWSER% "http://www.cnn.com"
ping -n 10 localhost>nul
START "" "http://www.gmail.com"
```

Comment: it's opening both sites in two different pages and the ping is not working, it opens both of them almost at the same time